# SQL Server 2008 Policies: Email on Failure

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a SQL Server Policy that forces databases (with exceptions) to be in Full Recovery.  Issue is that facet doesn't allow for "on change:prevent" so i have it on a schedule.  Is there a way to get an email anytime the policy fails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You likely considered setting an alert based upon the message number associated with the failure and let this generate the email (via dbmail).

Comment: Thanks... here's an article about it:
 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510667.aspx